# How to evaluate and add string to numpy array element

Tags: python, string, performance, numpy

Have this piece of code that I am trying to optimize.
It uses list comprehensions and works.

```
series1 = np.asarray(range(10)).astype(float)
series2 = series1[::-1]

ntup = zip(series1,series2)
[['', 't:'+str(series2)][series1 > series2] for series1,series2 in ntup ]
 #['', '', '', '', '', 't:4.0', 't:3.0', 't:2.0', 't:1.0', 't:0.0']
```

Trying to use `np.where()` here. Is there a solution with `numpy`. (Without series being consumed)

```
series1 = np.asarray(range(10)).astype(float)
series2 = series1[::-1]  

np.where(series1 >  series2 ,'t:'+ str(series2),'' )
```

The results is this:

```
array(['', '', '', '', '', 't:[ 9.  8.  7.  6.  5.  4.  3.  2.  1.  0.]',
       't:[ 9.  8.  7.  6.  5.  4.  3.  2.  1.  0.]',
       't:[ 9.  8.  7.  6.  5.  4.  3.  2.  1.  0.]',
       't:[ 9.  8.  7.  6.  5.  4.  3.  2.  1.  0.]',
       't:[ 9.  8.  7.  6.  5.  4.  3.  2.  1.  0.]'], 
      dtype='|S43')
```

Comment: Do you need those empty ones too or something like this is okay too - `['t:4.0', 't:3.0', 't:2.0', 't:1.0', 't:0.0']`?

Comment: I need empty values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a vectorized approach based on

- [`np.core.defchararray.add`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.add.html) for the string appending of `'t:'` with the valid strings, and
- [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to choose based on the conditional statement and perform the appending or just use the default value of an empty string.

So, we would have an implementation like so -

```
np.where(series1>series2,np.core.defchararray.add('t:',series2.astype(str)),'')
```

---

**Boost it-up!**

We can use the appending with `np.core.defchararray.add` on the valid elements based on the mask of `series1>series2` to boost up the performance further after initializing an array with the default empty strings and then assigning only the valid values into it.

So, the modified version would look something like this -

```
mask = series1>series2
out = np.full(series1.size,'',dtype='U34')
out[mask] = np.core.defchararray.add('t:',series2[mask].astype(str))
```

---

**Runtime test**

Vectorized versions as functions :

```
def vectorized_app1(series1,series2):
    mask = series1>series2
    return np.where(mask,np.core.defchararray.add('t:',series2.astype(str)),'')

def vectorized_app2(series1,series2):
    mask = series1>series2
    out = np.full(series1.size,'',dtype='U34')
    out[mask] = np.core.defchararray.add('t:',series2[mask].astype(str))
    return out
```

Timings on a bigger dataset -

```
In [283]: # Setup input arrays
     ...: series1 = np.asarray(range(10000)).astype(float)
     ...: series2 = series1[::-1]
     ...: 

In [284]: %timeit [['', 't:'+str(s2)][s1 > s2] for s1,s2 in zip(series1, series2)]
10 loops, best of 3: 32.1 ms per loop # OP/@hpaulj's soln

In [285]: %timeit vectorized_app1(series1,series2)
10 loops, best of 3: 20.5 ms per loop

In [286]: %timeit vectorized_app2(series1,series2)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.4 ms per loop
```

As noted by [`OP in comments`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256365/how-to-evalute-and-add-string-to-numpy-array-element#comment65850443_39256849), that we can probably play around with the dtype for `series2` before appending. So, I used `U32` there to keep the output dtype same as with `str` dtype, i.e. `series2.astype('U32')` inside the `np.core.defchararray.add` call. The new timings for the vectorized approaches were -

```
In [290]: %timeit vectorized_app1(series1,series2)
10 loops, best of 3: 20.1 ms per loop

In [291]: %timeit vectorized_app2(series1,series2)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.1 ms per loop
```

So, there's some further marginal improvement there!

Answer (score 1):

Your list comprehensions work just fine for lists, not really need to use arrays.  And for operations like this arrays probably won't give any speed advantage.

```
In [521]: series1=[float(i) for i in range(10)]
In [522]: series2=series1[::-1]
In [523]: [['', 't:'+str(s2)][s1 > s2] for s1,s2 in zip(series1, series2)]
Out[523]: ['', '', '', '', '', 't:4.0', 't:3.0', 't:2.0', 't:1.0', 't:0.0']
```

As @Divaker noted there is a `np.char.add` function that will perform string operations.  My experience is that they are marginally faster than list operations.  And when you take into account the overhead of creating arrays, they may be slower.

=========

The `array` version as shown by @Divakar

```
In [539]: aseries1=np.array(series1)
In [540]: aseries2=np.array(series2)
In [541]: np.where(aseries1>aseries2, np.char.add('t:',aseries2.astype('U3')), '
     ...: ')
Out[541]: 
array(['', '', '', '', '', 't:4.0', 't:3.0', 't:2.0', 't:1.0', 't:0.0'], 
      dtype='<U5')
```

A couple of time tests:

```
In [542]: timeit [['', 't:'+str(s2)][s1 > s2] for s1,s2 in zip(series1, series2)
     ...: ]
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.5 µs per loop

In [543]: timeit np.where(aseries1>aseries2, np.char.add('t:',aseries2.astype('U3')), '')
10000 loops, best of 3: 63 µs per loop
```

Comment: Maybe benchmark on bigger arrays? Also, isn't OP dealing with arrays as inputs?

Comment: The code sample is used constantly.  the arrays sizes are 10,000-5,000, can be a few arrays in conditional. On benchmarking,  it worth re-write on some.

Comment: np.core.defchararray.add('t:',series2.astype(str)) is faster than np.char.add('t:',aseries2.astype('U3')) -- its the unicode converion.

Comment: I used 'U3' because I'm on Py3; there `str` does the same thing.  On a Py2 session, `str` and `S3` should be the same.  `U3` will create longer arrays.

Comment: @Merlin Incorporated that idea into the timings in my post.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Fully vectorized.

```
import numpy as np
series1 = np.arange(10)
series2 = series1[::-1]
empties = np.repeat('', series1.shape[0])
ts = np.repeat('t:', series1.shape[0])
s2str = series2.astype(np.str)
m = np.vstack([empties, np.core.defchararray.add(ts, s2str)])
cmp = np.int64(series1 > series2)
idx = np.arange(m.shape[1])
res = m[cmp, idx]
print res
```

Comment: can you add timing?